# I'm building a login system with laravel, it seems to be working but when I reload the page it sends me back to the login form, user disconnected

Tags: laravel, authentication, controller

here's  the code of my controller

```
public function dologin(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->input('email');

    $password = $request->input('password');

    $customer = Customer::where('email', $email)->first();

    if ($customer && $customer->email === $email && Hash::check($password, $customer->password)) {
        Auth::login($customer);
        $user = Auth::user();
        $photo = Auth::user()->photo;
       return view ('customerprofile',$user);
       //return redirect()->route('customerprofile');
    } else {
        return back()->withErrors([
            'email' => ['Les informations de connexion sont incorrectes.'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

I want the user to be redirected on the page customerprofile and to stay logged in for 5 minutes

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you should not be returning a view from this action ... you should only be redirecting ... POST REDIRECT GET ... your action should have one responsibility, to log them in, then you should redirect them where they need to go ... let that redirect handle the next responsibility (either the profile route: which shows the profile ... or back to login: which would show the login)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I get an error when I try to only redirect

Comment: okay, so what error?

Comment: I get this error Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent(): Argument #1 ($content) must be of type ?string, Illuminate\Routing\Redirector given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\mp.bj\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php on line 72

Comment: that is because you didn't return a redirect ... show the code you used

Comment: If you want to do manual authentication, you should refer to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication#authenticating-users) for login and logout, or its better you use the [Breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/starter-kits) Starter kit with Blade or Livewire if you are new to Laravel

Comment: I just put this at the end
               return redirect();
            } else {
                return back()->withErrors([
                    'email' => ['Les informations de connexion sont incorrectes.'],
                ]);
            }
    }

Comment: I tried to use Breeze but everytime I type npm install it throws errors

Comment: that isn't a redirect (where are you telling it to redirect to? should it just redirect to some random URL on the internet?) ... and add code to your question not in the comments .... the actual redirect you have commented out in your question should work fine assuming you named the route that name

Comment: how do I do that please?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/responses#redirects ... are you redirecting to a path in your application, a route name?

Comment: I tried this return redirect ('customerprofile'); But it didn't work

Comment: what "didn't work" about it?

Comment: I cannot access a variable that I have passed to the view. I get this error : Undefined variable $photo

Comment: The issue is that when I do : return view('customerprofile', $user). It doesn't redirect me to the customerprofile page but I can see the customerprofile page with the user data, but the page vanishes once I reload